# How do I copy params from the current URI to a redirect URI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My code contains the following:

```
redirect_to some_rails_path(some_value)
```

However the redirect path needs to have the same URI params as the current path. How do I do that with **Rails 4.2**?

Comment: you can get params value with `some_rails_path(params[:some_params])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your params hash:

```
redirect_to some_rails_path(some_value, params.to_h)
```